# Simple.data how to get the last id in a record

Tags: c#, sql, simple.data

I have to check a set of records with an id structure using simple.data.
is there  a way where i can find the last id entered?  in reg sql i would do something like select top 1 of something desc but i am unsure of how to do it with simple.data.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to how you would do if in SQL. I am assuming here that you have the `id` column set as an identity column or something, so to correctly order it I will order it by the `id` column, then get the top result:

```
db.TableName
    .All()
    .OrderByDescending(db.TableName.IdColumnName)
    .First()
    .IdColumnName
```